# Please help with expressing a variable from an equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have this equation: $x=2^y/(1+2^y)$
How to express "$y$"?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Write $$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1+2^y}{2^y}=1+\frac{1}{2^y}$$
Can you finish?
So $$y=\log_{2}\frac{x}{1-x}$$
we have $$\frac{1-x}{x}=\frac{1}{2^y}$$ so $$2^y=\frac{x}{1-x}$$

Comment: Please could you write step by step? I am not sure how you did it.. I can only express that as y=log/log style, which is not very pretty.. I am here: $2^y = x/(1-x)$ . What should I do next?

Comment: Take the logarithm to the base $2$

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my stupidity..

Comment: No one is stupid, only to blind to see the solution